# Get a warning of active-users on windows using shell script

Tags: bash, shell, awk, command-line, grep

I'm trying to write a shell script that returns a warning if more than one user is aktive on a shared virtual machine.

So essentially, the output of the command `query user` must be piped to e.g awk and then the staus must be checked. So if there is more than one active status, the script returns a warning with the output of `query user` command highlighting the active users. By highlighting the active users i mean for example to give a line of the active users a green background color

[image]

```
Concept
query user | awk 'function to test how many users are active and retun a warning with highlighted active users if more than one is active'
```

Please note, this must not be done only with awk. I believe grep should also do the work. However, i'm a beginner in shell scripting since  started this month.

Hope you could help me and thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks for sharing your efforts in your question, please do post output of `query user` command in text form of your question so that we can test our solutions on it, thank you.

Comment: SO is not a coding service.

Comment: `| grep -c "Aktiv"` will tell you how many active users are on your system.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 thanks for the comment. The output of query user is shown in the image. I've just hidden the name of the users for private data reasons. Though i believe the status is what counts i mean where i should focus on. Users can be every time different

Comment: @Nic3500. Thanks for the comment. This is really promising and solves part of my problem. However, i'm trying in adition to label the active users with green color background. So when there is more than one active user, it should return the usual output of query users however every acrive user gets a green background color

Comment: @Roadowl. I'm a ware that this is nit a coding service. However, i believe this is a site where one shares his problem to get help and learn sth practical. I also believe that is  far better to get an answer for something from someone who could directly give an answer, instead of wasting time searching for it. Thanks for the comment

Comment: `|grep -c "Aktiv"` tells you how many are active.  If this number is >1, run another `|grep "Aktiv"` to show which users have that status.  Or capture the output of the `|grep "Aktiv"` in a variable and count the number of lines in the output.  If >1, display the output.  FYI: for the site usage, you will learn much more if you "fight" the problem and research a solution, than if you get a solution right away.  I could have given you a complete script, but with the grep commands, you can get started and learn how to code a complete solution.  If you get stuck, after research, then post.

Comment: @Zang322 :  I would separate the problem and ask two questions here on [so]: Finding the right information is one, and outputting some text in a colour of your  choice is a different one.

Comment: @user1934428. I would happy to do so. However, i would also would be glad if Nic2500 post his comment as an answer.

Comment: @Nic3500 Can you please post your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`|grep -c "Aktiv"` tells you how many are active. If this number is >1, run another `|grep "Aktiv"` to show which users have that status.

Or capture the output of the `|grep "Aktiv"` in a variable and count the number of lines in the output. If >1, display the output.

Ex:

```
#!/bin/bash

output=$(grep "Aktiv" input_file.txt)
count=$(echo "$output" | wc -l)

if [[ "$count" -gt 1 ]]
then
    echo "$output"
fi
```

Comment: Would be glat if you could give my question a vote up :)